# Unknown prop `herf` on <a> tag react

Tags: reactjs

I am new to `reactjs`.I am trying to set `herf` attribute to the anchor element but getting warning like `Unknown prop herf on <a> tag. Remove this prop from the element`.

In `employees.js.jsx` file:

```
var Employees = React.createClass({
render: function() {
employees = this.props.props.employees.map( function(employee) {
  return (
    <tr key={employee.id}>
      <td>{employee.name}</td>
      <td>{employee.email}</td>
      <td>{employee.manager}</td>
      <td><a herf={'/employees/' + employee.id}>Edit</a></td>
    </tr>
  );
});....
```

How do i set `herf` attribute to the element.Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `herf` attribute for anchor element, change `herf` to `href`.